# ess won't fully install ubuntu 12.04

Tags: emacs, ubuntu-12.04, ess

The last time I ran sudo apt-get upgrade ess gave this error and now says its not fully installed. I checked and installed all dependencies and couldn't find any other reports of this issue.

```
enabling speedbar support
[ess-r-d:] (autoload ..) & (def** ..)
Wrong number of arguments: define-obsolete-function-alias, 3
xemacs exiting
.
emacs-package-install: /usr/lib/emacsen-common/packages/install/ess xemacs21 emacs23 xemacs21 failed at /usr/lib/emacsen-common/emacs-package-install line 30, <TSORT> line 1.
dpkg: error processing ess (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ess
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: There are many problematic states that could provoke this. 

`sudo dpkg -r ess` `sudo apt-get check` `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing` `sudo apt-get install ess` 

half of that is unnessesary hopefully but it stands a good chance of squashing it.

Comment: Also not really the right subdomain to ask this one, maybe move it to superuser, unix/linux or askubuntu.com

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. The comment from Max solved it:

```
sudo dpkg -r ess 
sudo apt-get check 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing 
sudo apt-get install ess
```